Is there a philosophical/non-logical version of the principle of bivalence?
I have seen philosophical versions of the principles of excluded middle and non-contradiction, which I guess were first formulated by Aristotle. Things like "A thing cannot possess and not possess a certain property at the same time" (non-contradiction) and "A thing must either possess a certain property, not possess that property or possess and not possess it at the same time, but it cannot do neither" (excluded middle).
Two questions:

Are these two philosophical versions of the LNC and LEM correct? The logical version of LNC says that "bread is food" cannot be true and false at the same time, implying that bread cannot both be and not be food at the same time, which agrees with the philosophical version of LNC. The logical version of LEM says that at least one of "bread is food" and "bread is not food" must be true, so either bread is food, bread is not food or bread is and isn't food at the same time, which agrees with the philosophical version.

I understand it's probably not even a canonical "thing," but what would be the philosophical version of the principle of bivalence? Is it "Either a thing possesses a property or it doesn't"? I've seen people say that this is the philosophical version of the law of excluded middle but that doesn't sit well with me.



There aren't separate logical and philosophical versions of LEM and LNC. The version you attribute to Aristotle is expressed in terms of a thing having a property or not because Aristotle was concerned with propositions in subject/predicate form. But it we consider propositions more generally, LEM states that P ∨ ¬P is a theorem, and LNC states that ¬(P ∧ ¬P) is a theorem. Bivalence is about truth values: it states that a proposition is either true or false and not both.

In informal contexts, there is no difference between bivalence and the law of the excluded middle. Informal contexts don't generally distinguish between proofs and models.

Look at user3872's reply in this thread: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/7246/86652
""At this juncture, it might be helpful to state the law of excluded middle for properties, which is a second-order logical truth: Given any property and given any individual, either the individual has that property or it does not have that property. [Please note that it doesn't matter what the property is or what the individual is.]"
This person seems to be saying that there is a different version of the law of excluded middle for individuals/properties.

@DavidGudeman The distinction between LEM and bivalence is not related to the distinction between proofs and models. In classical logic, P ∨ ¬P is a theorem and it is also a tautology. Both of those might be considered expressions of LEM, though we usually think of it as a theorem. By contrast, P is true or P is false is a metalevel statement about the possible truth values of P. That is bivalence. LEM is about negation; BV is about truth values. Classical logic has both, but in some systems we can have one without the other.

@logiclearner That quote is interesting. In modern logic we negate propositions and not properties, so the negation of Fa is ¬Fa. LEM still simplifies down to an instance of P ∨ ¬P. But it is correct that Aristotle speaks of a thing possessing a property or not, and you might choose to represent this as a second order quantified sentence over properties. However it still boils down to P ∨ ¬P unless you extend the logic somehow to allow a predicate to be negated by constructing its complement.

@Bumble, historical expressions of the LEM generally are something like "every expression is either true or false" which sure sounds like it is about truth values. This notion that it has only to do with form is new, invented along with proof theory and model theory, and is not something that earlier logicians would have thought of.

@DavidGudeman I don't think that is the case. Aristotle distinguished between the two and so did the stoics. Most medieval logicians followed Aristotle. A few logicians of the modern period such as Leibniz appear to have conflated them. Frege and Russell identified negation with falsehood, but that was a mistake based on a failure to distinguish between object language and metalanguage. It was rightly criticised by Quine, Austin, Geach and others. By the time we get to Heyting, Kleene and Łukasiewicz, the distinction is firmly established.

Law of noncontradiction:

it states that contradictory propositions cannot both be true in the same sense at the same time, e. g. the two propositions "the house is white" and "the house is not white" are mutually exclusive.

With Aristotle's terminology: "A thing cannot possess and not possess a certain property at the same time".
Law of excluded middle:

it states that for every proposition, either this proposition or its negation is true.

With Aristotle's terminology: "A thing must either possess a certain property, or not possess that property."
Principle of bivalence:

tates that every declarative sentence expressing a proposition has exactly one truth value, either true or false. A logic satisfying this principle is called a two-valued or bivalent logic.

You are asking:

Are these two philosophical versions of the LNC and LEM correct?

Wrt LEM, your version: "A thing must either possess a certain property, not possess that property or possess and not possess it at the same time, but it cannot do neither" is not correct. If you add the clause "possess and not possess it at the same time" you are contradicting LNC.
Wrt the question:

what would be the philosophical version of the principle of bivalence?

it regards the truth-value of declarative statements, stating that logic have to consider only statenments having a well-defined truth value. Thus, sentences that predict events in the future, sentences that are open to interpretation (see e.g. Vagueness) do not fit in the "logical model" adopting the principle.

Thank you for your answer. Isn't the LEM based on the inclusive "or," though? So, shouldn't Aristotle's version be, "A thing must possess a certain property and/or not possess that property"?

Surely the asker's formulation of the LEM is equivalent to yours. (A or B) is logically equivalent to (A or B or [A and B]); the latter just isn't particularly terse.
